# Using Jackson to serialize xml using attributes without annotations

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I am currently writing some code using Jackson to serialize legacy POJOs into XML, but I need them to be serialized using attributes not child elements.  Is there a way to do this using Jackson without adding annotations to the legacy classes?

Answer (score 8):

> Is there a way to do this using Jackson without adding annotations to the legacy classes?

You can try to use [Mix-in](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/08/entry_305.html) annotations in jackson. In this way you can preserve your legacy classes and the same time you will enjoy the annotations feature. Here's how.

**Person.class**

```
   class Person {
        private String username;
        private String lastName;
        private String address;
        private Integer age;
        //getters and setters 

    }
```

**Mixin.class**

```
abstract class Mixin{
@JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    abstract String getUsername();

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    abstract String getLastName();

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    abstract String getAddress();

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    abstract String getAge();

}
```

**Main method**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    Person p = new Person("Foo","Bar");
    p.setAddress("This address is too long");
    p.setAge(20);

    ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();

    xmlMapper.addMixInAnnotations(Person.class, MixIn.class);
    String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(p);
    System.out.println(xml);
}
```

**Output**

```
<Person xmlns="" username="Foo" lastName="Bar" address="This address is too long" age="20"></Person>
```

Comment: Yesss! thank you for providing such a clear + WORKING example for using Mixin + Jackson XML Mapper