# Java+Jackson+XML: serialize a java object properties as XML elements with same names

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have a Java object and I would like to serialize it into **XML** using **Jackson** library:

```
public class Point {
    private Integer x;
    private Integer y;
    //getters/setters
}
```

and I would like to serialize it into following format:

```
<point>
    <property name="x" value="1" />
    <property name="y" value="1" />
</point>
```

instead of what I get using Jacskon:

```
<point>
    <x>1</x>
    <y>1</y>
</point>
```

I do not want to change the `Point` object properties or structure. Is there a way 
to serialize the `Point` object into required format using a Jackson annotations or custom serializer? If yes then how do I do that?

I am using Jackson library:

```
public class Serializer {
    XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();

    public void serialize(File file, Object object) throws IOException {
        mapper.writeValue(file, object);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837401/using-jackson-to-serialize-xml-using-attributes-without-annotations/26840723#26840723

Comment: @MichalFoksa Mixins solve another kind of issue - I can use annotations with or without mixins, but the problem remains: how to serialize into requested format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mark those properties as attributes like this:

```
public class Point {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private Integer x;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private Integer y;
    //getters/setters
}
```